# Biblography in acmart document

Tags: bibliographies, acmart

I have got a very simple and probably also pretty easy to solve problem but since I am new to TEX I do not find the solution myself. I am kind of forced to use the acmart template for a report I am writing, meaning that I have to use \documentclass{acmart}. Of course I need a biblography as well, and I used those in some other short reports as well, but they don't seem to work inside acmart (at least the way I used to use them).

```
\documentclass[]{acmart}
\usepackage[]{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\title{...}
\subtitle{...}
\author{...}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
... \cite{asdf} ...
\bibliography{biblo}
\biblographystyle{plainnat}
\end{document}
```

The biblography file I use is called "biblo.bib" and contains only one reference so far:

```
@online{asdf,
    author = "asdf",
    year = "1970",
    title = "...",
    url = "...",
    month = oct,
    lastaccessed = "July 19, 2017", 
}
```

However for one the biblography is not printed at the end of my report and also the citation is not resolved. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The acmart documentations states: "ACM uses the `natbib` package [...] you can select one of two predefined citation styles: [...] for example, `\citestyle{acmauthoryear}`" (p. 22), "If you use `natbib`, then commands like `\citep` and `\citeauthor` are automatically supported." If you want to use numeric style, you should probably use `\cite` and `\citestyle{acmnumeric}` instead. If it still does not work, check if you run BibTeX at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the style of your bibliography with `\bibliographystyle{style}` where `style` is a `natbib` style like for instance `plainnat`. Working example is then:

```
\documentclass[]{acmart}
\usepackage[]{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\title{...}
\subtitle{...}
\author{...}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
... \cite{asdf} ...
\bibliography{biblo}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\end{document}
```

Output is then:
[image: Output is then:]

Comment: Thank you very much, but it seems that this does not change anything concerning my problem.

Comment: This works for me, are you compiling with bibtex?

Comment: I am using pdfTex inside TexStudio, and even if I try to compile this very abreviated example i posted (plus your addition) it does not look like what tex.stackexchange makes it look like.

Comment: Okay nevermind, I do not know why, but biblatex was excluded form my build command. Sorry for the unnecessary fuzz and thank you!

Comment: On a different note I would recommend switching to latexmk